# Manipulating a factor and category in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, spread, dcast

So i have a data set i am trying to manipulate and i cant seem to find the right way to do this. Iv looked into using dcast and spread but not sure how to get the right manipulation.

so i have something like:

```
ID var1 var2 var3 category
--------------------------
1  x    x    x     a
1  x    x    x     b
1  x    x    x     b
2  y    y    y     a
2  y    y    y     b
2  y    y    y     c
3  z    z    z     b 
3  z    z    z     b
3  z    z    z     c
```

Id like it to look like this:

```
ID var1 var2 var3  a  b  c 
--------------------------------
1  x    x    x     1  1  0 
2  y    y    y     1  1  1
3  z    z    z     0  1  1
```

Easy example data

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
var1 <- c('x','x','x','y','y','y','z','z','z')
var2 <- c('x','x','x','y','y','y','z','z','z')
var3 <- c('x','x','x','y','y','y','z','z','z')
category <- c('a','b','b','a','b','c','b','b','c')

dat <- data.frame(ID,var1,var2,var3,category)
```

Comment: Check `tidyr` package to reshape your dataset.

Comment: You need quotes when you create your var1 to var3. Eg. "x".

Comment: `library(tidyr); dat %>% 
  group_by_all() %>% 
  summarise(v=1) %>% 
  spread(category, v, fill=0)`. Or, if you want to count the number of values in each group: `dat %>% 
  group_by_all() %>% 
  tally %>% 
  spread(category, n, fill=0)`.

Comment: @AntoniosK i gave em some quotes

Comment: To save some typing when creating your data, you can do `rep(c('x','y','z'), each=3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
var1 <- c("x","x","x","y","y","y","z","z","z")
var2 <- c("x","x","x","y","y","y","z","z","z")
var3 <- c("x","x","x","y","y","y","z","z","z")
category <- c("a","b","b","a","b","c","b","b","c")

dat <- data.frame(ID,var1,var2,var3,category)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  distinct() %>%                   # get distinct rows
  mutate(value = 1) %>%            # create a counter
  spread(category, value, fill=0)  # reshape dataset

#   ID var1 var2 var3 a b c
# 1  1    x    x    x 1 1 0
# 2  2    y    y    y 1 1 1
# 3  3    z    z    z 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question is tagged with `dcast`, I feel obliged to post a concise solution using `dcast()`.

The OP has not explained how the columns in the wide format should be computed. From the expected result it seems that the OP is *not* interested in counting the number of occurrences but to indicate presence or absence of each unique combination (`1`/`0` in place of `TRUE`/`FALSE`).

Therefore, only unique rows are included in the reshape operation. `length()` is still used as aggregation function because it fills empty cells with 0 as requested.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(unique(dat), ... ~ category, length)
```

> ```
>   ID var1 var2 var3 a b c
> 1  1    x    x    x 1 1 0
> 2  2    y    y    y 1 1 1
> 3  3    z    z    z 0 1 1
> ```